# Converting Date to 08:00:00.000+0000

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-time

I am calling a rest web service that accepts Date. On client side, i have calling this service using JDK 8 OffsetDateTime Class.

```
Value that is going from my client side : 2018-07-01T05:30+05:30
Value that is accepted by Service : 2018-07-01T08:00:00.000+0000
```

Below is the code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
cal.set(2018, 05, 31);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(cal.getTime().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Value of offsetDateTime that is coming with above code is 2018-07-01T05:30+05:30.

I am in IST time zone.
Can someone help as to what needs to be done to change date to 2018-07-01T08:00:00.000+0000.

Comment: When you can use `OffsetDateTime`, avoid the old, out-dated and poorly designed `Calendar` class completely. java.time, the modern Java date and time API, offers all the functionality you need (and more).

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Your comments make it a bit unclear: Do you need an `OffsetDateTime` object, a `String` or both?

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

If you want 8 AM on first day of July at UTC…

```
OffsetDateTime.of( 
    2018 , 7 , 1 ,     // Date (year, month 1-12 is Jan-Dec, day-of-month)
    8 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,    // Time (hour, minute, second, nano)
    ZoneOffset.UTC     // Offset-from-UTC (0 = UTC)
)                      // Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object.
.format(               // Generates a `String` object with text representing the value of the `OffsetDateTime` object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" , Locale.US )
)                      // Returns a `String` object.
```

> 2018-07-01T08:00:00.000+0000

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use `Calendar` or `Date` classes. They were completely supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes such as [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). You are mixing the legacy classes with the modern, and that makes no sense.

## java.time

Your Question is not clear about what are your inputs and what are your outputs versus your expectations.

If you goal is 8 AM on July 1 in UTC:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JULY , 1 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 8 , 0 ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( ld , lt , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2018-07-01T08:00Z

That string format complies with [ISO 8061](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. If your destination refuses that input and accepts only `2018-07-01T08:00:00.000+0000`, then we must defining a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" , Locale.US );
String output = odt.format( f );
```

> 2018-07-01T08:00:00.000+0000

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

i think the below code will work

```
public static Date ConvertToGMT() {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date utc = new Date(dateFormat.format(date));
    return utc;
}
```

Comment: Executing this code gave output : Fri Aug 10 06:09:43 IST 2018 . I need date in T08:00:00.000+0000 kind of format.

Comment: Also, i need date with OffsetDateTime class while the above code returns  Date class.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so,

```
   offsetDateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))
```

**Update**

If you need an instance of `OffsetDateTime` here it is.

```
offsetDateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).toOffsetDateTime();
```

Comment: This returns object of ZonedDateTime while i need object of OffsetDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not the answer you asked for, but it may be the answer you prefer in the end: Check once more whether the service you are calling accepts the format that you are already giving it. Both formats conform with ISO 8601, so it seems that the service accepts this standard format. If so, it should accept yours too.

In any case, use `OffsetDateTime` and the other classes from java.time exclusively and avoid the old and outdated `Calendar` and `TimeZone` classes. Basil Bourque’s answer shows the good solution.

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)